# Invalid shares? using Dualminer through Nanopool

Tags: go-ethereum, mining-pools

So, i have just started using Dual Miner V8.0 and i have been in email contact with nanopool support and it seems i am mining alot of invalid shares. In my code i am not seeing any notification for an invalid share only a green text pop up when i do indeed find shares. I have update my GPUs drivers to its most recent update drivers (gpu is ,MSI GAMING Radeon RX 480 GDDR5 4GB CrossFire VR Ready FinFET DirectX 12 Graphics Card (RX 480 ARMOR 4G OC), driver Radeon Software Crimson ReLive Edition 17.2.1), i also have corrected any abnormalities in my config.txt file and epool.txt file. I have registered 1 single share on nanopools website but since have not had another one pop up. EVEN THOUGH i have logs stating ive found over 200 shares now running my computer periodically over the last two days. If anyone could shed some light on why i am not getting any shares to validate it would be much appreciated. if pictures are needed i can post what ever else in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to mine Ethereum, correct?

If nanopool has registered at least one accepted share, then you are properly connected.

Since you're using Dualminer, you've likely been mining other coins as well, which would explain why nanopool is showing so few accepted shares.